# Angularjs $on method recive many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's look at the code first,blow is my Button directive

```
.directive('ajaxButton', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
        action: '&'   
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var formHtml = $(elem).html();
      function buttonStatus(status) {

        var loadText = status == 'start' ? '提交...' : formHtml;
        var isDisabled = status == 'start' ? true : false;
        $(elem).attr('disabled',isDisabled).html(loadText);

      }

      elem.click(function(){
        buttonStatus('start');
        //-------call function -------------
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.action();             
        });

        //-------listen events-----------------
        scope.$on('httpend:success',function() {
            $.ambiance({
                message: "success！", 
                title: "message",
                type: "success"
            });            
            console.log('success!!!');
            buttonStatus('end');
        });
      });
    }
};
```

});

and this is my factory service and Controller:

```
homepage.controller('homeCtrl',function ($scope,homeservice,$rootScope) {
homeservice
    .getData()
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.model = JSON.parse(data.homepage);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpend');
    });
$scope.model = {
    homeTitle: 'this is home title',
    keyword: 'this is keyword',
    messageCover: 'http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/6538fd8cjw1eb0jzna64mj209605kaa7.jpg',
    logoImg: 'http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/6538fd8cjw1eb0jzna64mj209605kaa7.jpg',
    homgBg: 'http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/6538fd8cjw1eb0jzna64mj209605kaa7.jpg'
};
$scope.updateData = function () {
    homeservice.
        saveData({data: JSON.stringify($scope.model) })
        .success(function (data) {
            if(data) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpend:success');
            }   
        });
};
```

})
.factory('homeservice',function ($http) {
    return {
        saveData: function (data) {
            return $http.post('/wcsite', data);
        },
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get('/wcsite/data');
        }
    };
});

As you can see: while the ajax request get succed ,$rootScope will $broadcast message:'httpend',but while I revice many message ,and the message number is add everytime....Any one who can help me?Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the httpend:success handler outside of the element click handler.